# image buttons or layouts onclick?

Tags: android, image

In some apps there are the following ,followers and posts , are they image buttons in android ofcourse or its layout that used onclick method ?

because as you see the word "following" stay the same but the number change .So do we used image buttons and put textview above it ? I think about that while thinking about if I tried to offer it in a different languages .

Comment: you have to combine the ImageView and TextView for that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can make your own custom view and extend Button
and add multiple view to it then handle click on each view.
please explain more your question...
main.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.mhp.customimagebtn"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical" >
<!--other tags here-->

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/following"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:background="@drawable/bg"
        android:onClick="followingClick" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/following_number"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:text="0" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Following"
            android:textColor="#eee"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/follower"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:background="@drawable/bg"
        android:onClick="followerClick" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/follower_number"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:text="0" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Following"
            android:textColor="#eee"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
<!--other tags here-->
</LinearLayout>
```

bg.xml

```
<selector
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" >

    <item android:state_pressed="true">
        <shape>
            <gradient
                android:startColor="#f00"
                android:endColor="#f00"
                android:angle="270"/>
            <stroke
                android:width="2dp"
                android:color="#eee"/>
            <corners
                android:radius="3dp" />

        </shape>
    </item>

    <item>
        <shape>
            <gradient
                android:startColor="#ccc"
                android:endColor="#ccc"
                android:angle="270"/>
            <stroke
                android:width="2dp"
                android:color="#ccc"/>
            <corners
                android:radius="3dp" />

        </shape>
    </item>
</selector>
```

main.class

```
public class Main extends Activity {

TextView followingNumber,followerNumber;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    followingNumber = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.following_number);
    followerNumber = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.follower_number);
}

public void setFollowingNumberText(String number){
    followingNumber.setText(number);//you can update number of following here
}

public void setFollowerNumberText(String number){
    followerNumber.setText(number);//you can update number of follower here
}

public void followingClick(View view){
    //do something
}

public void followerClick(View view){
    //do somthing
}
}
```

Comment: I mean in the apps in the following or followers view the number change every time someone follows so is it an imageview for click it or ?

Comment: imageview just get image as background but if you need some text on it (that may change) ,you need to make class and extend ImageButton and create TextView object and set text,... then add it to Imageview. another way is by canvas draw a text and on each change , change text and re draw

Comment: but I want to make it like a button that can move the user into a followers activity (page) .. do you have a link that lead to a tutorial ? in twitter,facebook,instagram .. there is a following and the number above it , I want to make like this . how can this be done ?

Comment: can you show me a pic about what you want.then I can give you that code.because there are many way to do this.

Comment: like this : http://android-apps.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/09/Twitter-Android-app-profile-page.png

Comment: in simple way you can use LinearLayout by Two TextView or other view in it and set onClick for LinearLayout with custom background to feel like button.In other way you can see this link : stackoverflow.com/a/25263821/3553815.